# conversion function is required?

Tags: oracle, nvarchar, nclob

In my oracle database contains table Text_Details, field F_TEXT is now an NCLOB field so anywhere this is used in WHERE-clause comparisons may require casting it to other datatypes (NVARCHAR2(4000)probably) for those comparisons.

```
Text_Details

---------------
Name       Data type
Id          Number

F_Text      NCLOB
```

any casting is required in where clause comparison with other data types(NVARCHAR2(4000))or any other data types?.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a LOBs in the WHERE clause. From the [documentation:](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions002.htm)

however you can use **to_char(F_Text)** in your where clause like this:

> SELECT * FROM WHERE to_char(F_Text) = 'something';